# Parse javascript query inside a loop

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, parse-platform

So I am quite new to javascript and unsure as to how to go about solving this issue. I know that the query is asynchronous so cannot execute inside a loop but do not know how to go about this.

Here I am calling a query to get a list of all users. There is then a for loop to go through each user, the second query gets executed for each user and uses that users username as part of the class name. Does anyone have any suggestions for what I should do?

```
var query = new Parse.Query(User);
                query.find({
                    success: function (results) {

                        $(".success1").show();
                        progressBar.max = results.length * 2;

                        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                            var object = results[i];
                            var Predictions = Parse.Object.extend("predictions" + object.get("username"));

                            var query2 = new Parse.Query(Predictions);
                            query2.equalTo("matchWeekID", weekNum.value);

                                query2.find({
```

This is where the code does not run. The query2.find runs once the for loop has been finished.